# Copying and transpose pasting from excel 2010 embedded email to other worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010

I receive an email in the following format, from an external reporting source:

```
Department  COUNT(*)
Contact Us  4
Customer Care Expired   1
Customer Care Premium   14
Customer Care Trial 8
```

In the outlook preview pane I want to copy the numerical data and paste it in to a worksheet open in Excel 2010 as follows:

```
Date    Contact Us  Customer Care Expired   Customer Care Premium   Customer Care Trial Customer Center
Fri 05/04/2013 12:00    4   1   14  8
```

I can't get paste > transpose function to show up after copying the data from the outlook based excel data, so I'm entering the data manually.

The master spread sheet needs to be in this vertical format as it is then used by a graphing tool that requires rows over columns. I can't get the provider to give me a row format report either.

Any advice on if this is possible, and why transpose is not available much appreciated.

P.S. I have checked for addons, none are selected (so not skype-related). And I do get that feature on a plain worksheet, just not when I'm trying to copy and paste from email to standalone excel.

Answer (score 1):

From any Outlook message you can paste a table into Excel successfully if you first paste it into a word document.  Then select the table (only) using the downward arrows at the top of each column.  You may need to condense the table columns to be able to select them all, but formatting of the columns doesn't matter.  After selection, copy and past into your Excel sheet.  Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the source and pasting it into Notepad - then copy from Notepad to Excel. Using Notepad as a middleman will remove any hidden formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I usually have tens of emails to go through at a time though so I'm trying to get the quickest method. Adding that step would be slower than entering all the data manually.